# Subsetting by year gives different results using ymd() vs. year()

Tags: r, lubridate

I am getting different nrows subsetting by year using ymd() and year() in package lubridate and I am trying to figure out what might be causing that disparity.

A 331kb CSV file with 10k dates is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwrIp0071Y2tRnlaRXN1dE54VlE). A url pointing to Google Drive and Dropbox kept throwing up errors, beyond my newbie skills to figure out.

```
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)

teaSet <- fread("../teaSet.csv", na.strings=c("NA","N/A", ""))
teaSet$opened <- ymd_hms(teaSet$opened, tz = "")
teaSet$year <- as.factor(teaSet$year) 

ymd2010 <- teaSet[opened >= ymd("2010-01-01") & opened <= ymd("2010-12-31"),]
#1480 obs.
year2010 <- teaSet[year(opened)==2010,]
#1483 obs

summary(teaSet$year)
#2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 
#1483 1408 1317 1414 1521 1701 1156
```

Can anyone explain what I am missing? I was subsetting by date range and then by year() and noticed the year() and ymd() counts were different. I created a factor column for years (and cleverly named it "year")to speed things up - my dataset has 13 million rows - but is not directly relevant to my question. Seemed like a good idea when I started. I did different sample sizes and the disparity remains across sizes. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I already tried setting time zone and it makes no difference. I did abstract the 3 disparate times, the first of which suggests there is something else going on: 
`# 1:2010-12-31 09:09:00  
# 2: 2010-12-31 20:49:58  
# 3: 2010-12-31 23:38:18`

Comment: Looking over the problem some more it looks like: `ymd("2010-12-31")` is 12:00 AM on the 31st and not 12 PM.  If you change opened <= ymd("2011-1-1") it should work.  I suggest setting the timezone to GMT to avoid that being another issue. - Good luck

Comment: Thank you! I changed the range to opened <= ymd("2011-1-1") and the count is now correct. I also tried opened <=ymd_hms("2010-12-31 23:59:59") and specifying hms worked too. It is very unintuitive, tho, why not specifying hms should result in a change to the ymd part of the date. My  locale is America/New_York  so the offset to UTC should not make a difference to the first of the disparate dates in my second comment above.   Can you put your last comment in as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over the problem some more it looks like: ymd("2010-12-31") is 12:00 AM on the 31st and not 12 PM.
There are 2 options which I see a possible solutions.  Use the next day in the filter or covert all of your date/times to just dates with GMT.

If you change opened <= ymd("2011-1-1") it will work.

```
require(lubridate)
library(data.table)

teaSet <- fread("teaSet.csv", na.strings=c("NA","N/A", ""))
teaSet$opened <- ymd_hms(teaSet$opened, tz = "")
teaSet$year <- as.factor(teaSet$year) 

ymd2010 <- teaSet[opened >= ymd("2010-01-01") & opened < ymd("2011-1-1"),]
print(dim(ymd2010))

#a second possible option - not as clean as the prior one
teaSet$opened <- ymd_hms(teaSet$opened, tz = "GMT")
ymd2010_2 <-teaSet[as.Date(opened) >= ymd("2010-01-01") & as.Date(opened) <= ymd("2010-12-31")]
print(dim(ymd2010_2))

year2010 <- teaSet[year(opened)==2010,]

print( dim(year2010 ))
summary(teaSet$year)
```

I agree the timezone issue is unintuitive, but it is what is it is.  Nice job on testing for and catching the inconsistence in your original solution.

Comment: And if you ever figure out or run into why it behaves this way - pl post. I waste a lot of time trying to get to the bottom of this kind of seeming irrationality. Also I hesitated to use your second suggestion to set tz to "GMT" because it has the potential to cause confusion later, if seeing UTC  ont he timestamp leads to then converting UTC to local time zone on the fly. I know I gave up trying to use fasttime because the help page said  "timezone for the resulting POSIXct object - this is NOT the time of x, that will always be GMT!" - confused the hell out of me.